# API for the number of sitelinks and statements

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, wikidata, mediawiki-api, wikidata-api

Which API response the number of sitelinks and statements given a query like the picture below? Seems to me it is not `wbgetclaims` and `wbsearchentities`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind people on Telegram group told me that it is `wb-claims` and `wb-sitelinks` page props https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=pageprops&generator=search&ppprop=wb-claims%7Cwb-sitelinks&gsrsearch=apple&gsrlimit=1

also available in queries https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ312%20wikibase%3Astatements%20%3Fstatements%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Asitelinks%20%3Fsitelinks.%0A%7D